# Dophin browser on android fail to recognize deep linking

Tags: android, dolphin-browser

I'm using deep linking on http scheme to let user open my app directly from a link such as http://myapp.com/invitation?code=xxxxxx

**It works fine as long as the user do not use the Browser named Dolphin, for example,the default android browser, Firefox and Chrome works fine**

Indeed, with this browser installed, the link will be directly opened in the browser and no where i have the context menu to "open link with" and be able to select my app.

Does anyone get the same behavior ?

Android 4 (API 19) or 5 (API 21).

```
 <activity
        android:name=".DeepLinkedActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="myapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/invitations"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```